# how to get context from PhoneStateListener class

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

i need to call method from several classes, but i don't know how to get the right context

the holding class:

```
public class SharedData {
......
......

    public static void stop_ring(Context context){

        Uri  lcurUri = RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context, RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        Ringtone ring = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, lcurUri);

        ring.stop();
    }
```

how can i call it from activity class, and how can i call it from PhoneStateListener class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Activity extends Context so you can call it like so:

```
SharedData.stop_ring(this);
```

For a listener you will have to put Context in the constructor and save it as a property. Then call:

```
SharedData.stop_ring(saved_context);
```

Comment: Thanks, 
SharedData.stop_ring(saved_context); Did the job.
but, SharedData.stop_ring(this); try to call this method with a difference context id

Comment: SharedData.stop_ring(this); can only be called inside a class that extends Context, ie. your Activity class. Are you trying to call it from somewhere else?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, this is how it looks like: " " class main extends LicenseCheckActivity "

Comment: If LiscenseCheckAcitvity extends Activity then you should be able to say SharedData.stop_ring(this); What exactly goes wrong when you do?

Comment: " public abstract class LicenseCheckActivity extends Activity { "
the problem is: it just keep playing the music, it supposed to stop.

Comment: Try calling it using getApplicationContext();

    SharedData.stop_ring(getApplicationContext());

Comment: Did not help.
i think it use a different context id

Comment: I assume that the activity that started the ringtone would be the only one that could stop it, do you start the song in you LicenseCheckActivity class?

Comment: But the context that it uses to start the ringtone, where does that come from?

Comment: thanks, now it works.
i use this code to get the right context from the working class:
    public Context getBaseContext()
    {
     return baseContext;
    }

Answer (score 2):

the major solution is

1.

```
public class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener 
{
    public MyPhoneStateListener(Context ctx) {
    super();        
}
```

2.

When istance the listener

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);telephonyManager.listen(
                       new MyPhoneStateListener(Context),
                       PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

3.

finish

by

Answer (score 0):

Try to use getApplicationContext(). Mostly it works.